# Do 4E Essentials Mages gain more Cantrips after 1st level?

Tags: dnd-4e, wizard

I was finally getting around to reading my 4E Essentials books, specifically the *Heroes of the Fallen Lands* Wizard, the Mage. After discovering the nice hybrid of Vancian and 4E Core magic, I noticed that a Mage, regardless of school, gains 3 Cantrips at 1st level.

What I'm getting at is this; Does a 4E Mage gain more Cantrips as they progess in level or do they *only* know the 3 Cantrips from levels 1 to 30?

Comment: After fiddling around with an Eladrin Mage I realized that they don't gain At-Wills either and are stuck with the 2 (3 if you count the standard Magic Missile) they began play with. I thought this was almost under-powering until I counted the sheer number of Encounter and Daily spells they get later in game!

Comment: Being them At-Wills, you don't really *need* to know more than 1 (2 is for some variety): you never run out of them. This is true for every D&D 4e class (except psionics, but psionics use slightly different mechanics). So, it's not like you will get stuck with no spells and be "underpowered"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**

They only know their cantrips they start the game with. However, it is reasonable to ask to learn an extra one as a feat, due to the precedent set with the Psion.

> Diverse Focus [Elan Bloodline]
>
> Heroic Tier
>
> Prerequisite: Elan Heritage, psion, Discipline Focus class feature
>
> Benefit: Choose and gain a Discipline Focus other than one you already possess. You can use any powers associated with that Discipline Focus as daily powers.

and with Gnome:

> Fey Trickster
>
> Heroic Tier
>
> Prerequisite: Gnome
>
> Benefit: You gain the wizard cantrips mage hand and prestidigitation as encounter powers.

As the cantrips are Wizard Utility spells without a level, it's impossible to take them in your utility slots. (Though that would be a perfectly reasonable house-rule, considering the relative utility of cantrips and utility powers.)